# I get a seemingly infinite loop when downloading Grand Theft Auto on demand

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I downloaded the install file (7gb) and then proceeded to download the extra install files (in reverse order). I got the first two downloaded but then I got to the the third one and it just keeps starting and stopping.

I get the message "download stopped for GTA V install pack 2" repeating every 10 seconds. Any ideas? Should I just delete everything and start over?

Comment: What did Rockstar say on their support forum?

Comment: I have same problem. Did you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a possiblity that you may not have space on the drive. Delete something you don't need if this is the case. Also if there is a usb stick in the Xbox the files may be downloaded to that. Check where the download is going to in the "Active Downloads". Also try to continue the download, it may tell you why.
If this is not the case, you may be trying to use a disk with the on demand disk 2 files (They do not work, it will say disk unreadable). Finally, check your storage and make sure there is 7Gb space free for the files. If it is GTA, go to your download history under account settings and redownload them there.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to home screen. It will still be active in download. The loading screen is just trying to install all packs as if it was being ripped from a cd